Error reading file from Synapse Analytics - Encoding issue in azure data factory
I currently try to copy files from a SFTP to a blob storage in azure with Azure Datafactory. In my SFTP, i got ANSI and UTF-8 files.
The copy is working fine with a copy activity in ADF (due to my error, i have a dataset for UTF8 files and a dataset for ANSI files using windows-1252 encoding, dont know if it's useful)
When i try to read the file encoded in ANSI in Synapse, i got this error :
Bulk load failed due to invalid column value in CSV data file schema.table in row 19, column 6.
18;"1";"1";" ";29/11/2010;"Brest";"FR";"FR";;;"14 rue le Saec";" ";"56700";"HENNEBONT";0;" ";" ";" ";" ";" ";;" "
19;"2";"2";" ";01/12/1950;"Vitré";"FR";"FR";;;"42 La Haulais";" ";"44260";"LA CHAPELLE LAUNAY";41;" ";" ";" ";" ";" ";;" "
When i try to read the file in blob storage, i got this error ->
Error in blob storage
But if i download the file and read it on desktop, everything is fine.
It seems it is a problem with handling ANSI because it's working fine if i convert my file to UTF8 with notepad++ and upload it afterwards.
I don't find a way to convert file in ADF. and i don't succeed to allow Synapse to read ANSI files. ( I tried a lot of things - dataset encoding, Collate in synapse..)
I try changing encoding, collate in database.
I want to be able to do select in synapse on ANSI Files, or convert ANSI files to UTF8

Which type of files you are trying to copy to blob storage? could you please provide your sample data?

it's CSV files delimited by ;

Is it possible to share sample data?

I have added two rows in the question ( row 18 and row 19, 19 with the error on "vitré"

Hi @user28397663, please check below answer, let me know is it helpful or not.

Here is the sample file which is encoded with ANSI I have taken:


I don't find a way to convert file in ADF. and i don't succeed to allow Synapse to read ANSI files. ( I tried a lot of things - dataset encoding, Collate in synapse..)

You can follow below procedure to convert file into required format:
Create a source dataset with below configuration:

Create a sink dataset with below configuration:

Use both datasets in copy activity in ADF pipeline, debug the pipeline, then you will be able to get the data in required format to read in synapse as shown below:

Then go to Synapse studio open target file location, right Click on it, select New SQL Script select Bulk load as shown below:

Configure it as shown below:

Click on continue, select db configuration as shown below:

After running the script, you will be able to read the file successfully without any error as shown below:

